# Absolute difference of sum of two diagonals of a 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I want to obtain the absolute difference of the sum of left and right diagonal of the given 2d array.
I have written the following function-

```
int diagonalDifference(vector<vector<int>> arr) {
    int n=arr.size();
    int summ1=0,summ2=0,result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   { for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
          if(i==j)
          { summ1=summ1+arr[i][j];}
          else if((i+j)==(n-1))
          { summ2=summ2+arr[i][j];}
      }
      
    }
    result=abs(summ1-summ2);
    return result;
}

input array
11 2 4
4  5 6
10 8 -12

Explanation- summ1=11+5+(-12)
             summ2=4++5+10    result=|4-19|=|-15|=15

expected output: 15
The output I am getting is 10
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and analyze it on a piece of paper?

Comment: No ... I think I should have done that.

Comment: By the way, instead of iterating through all cells, you could simply go with a single loop: `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { sum1 += arr[i][i]; sum2 += arr[i][n-i-1]; }`

Comment: @Aziuth Yes your method is much better than mine. I will do it.

Comment: Also consider passing `arr` to the function by `const` reference, rather than by value (which copies the vector passed by the caller).   Probably better not to have a function definition in which the argument list relies on `using namespace std` in effect i.e.  give it its full type of `const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &arr`.   You might also want to do a check that both dimensions are `n` - since accessing elements using `operator[]()` will have undefined behaviour if your loop runs out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in O(n) complexity. [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-difference-between-sums-of-two-diagonals/)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        summ1 += arr[i][i];
        summ2 += arr[i][n-i-1];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else-if` should be an `if` by itself.

The `else-if` prevents the `5` from being added to `summ2`. Which means the final calculation is: `(11+5-12)-(4+10) = -10.` Whose absolute value is `10`.